# Bootstrap 4: How to adjust the length of an input using the class input-group-append?

Tags: html, css, input, bootstrap-4

I am creating a pay rate with two input boxes for number's,

The problem I am running into is the input boxes are being stretched way to much causing the cent's file to drop down onto the next line. The Maxlength with bootstrap is being ignored, So I can adjust the length of the input box.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="pay_rate">Pay Rate</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
            </div>
            <input type="number" name="pay_rate" id="pay_rate" class="form-control" style="text-align: right;" placeholder="0" maxlength="4" size="4">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <input type="number" name="pay_rate" id="pay_rate" class="form-control" placeholder="00"maxlength="2" size="2">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

What is the best option to do money input field that will show the $ and cents? But when loading into SQL, I cant have the $ be entered into the database.

Comment: Do you mean input with instead of length? Also, your subject seems to be asking one question and you end your description with another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question... out of the box, it seems that having multiple `input-group-append` classes doesn't affect the last input boxes... so we gotta manage the width for it ourselves: We do this with the max-width property on it.

Working **snippet** below:

```css
.myClass {
  max-width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="pay_rate">Pay Rate</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
    </div>
    <input type="number" name="pay_rate" id="pay_rate" class="form-control" style="text-align: right;" placeholder="0" maxlength="4" size="4">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text">.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append myClass">
      <input type="number" name="pay_rate" id="pay_rate" class="form-control" placeholder="99" maxlength="4" size="4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```